# How to handle both GET and POST requests in TornadoWeb framework?

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I'm really new to Python community, it's been a while that I'm trying to learn Flask and Tornado frameworks.

As you know we can handle GET and POST requests together in Flask very easily, 
For example a simple URL routing in Flask is something like this:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    pass
```

I googled and read Tornado documentation but I couldn't find a way to handle both GET and POST requests together in Tornado.

All I found is like code below:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('intro.html')

    def post(self):
        self.render('intro.html')
```

Any idea how to do it in Tornado?

Comment: That's it.they are the `GET` and `POST` request handlers.

Comment: @ Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy - OP wants to do it in "Tornado"

Comment: @alecxe
Yes, I wanna do it in one method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go with using [prepare()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=requesthandler#tornado.web.RequestHandler.prepare) method:

> Called at the beginning of a request before get/post/etc.
>   Override this method to perform common initialization regardless of
>   the request method.

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.render('intro.html')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks nice and simple. My only concern would be this would not be the expected output for a `HEAD` request. But then again, neither would no output... so... closest I can see, short of a custom `RequestHanndler` class

Comment: @JonClements thank you! please see the edited code. Are you concerned about `HEAD` now? :)

Comment: 405: Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 2):

Ok.If you want to handle them together, try this

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.post()

    def post(self):
        self.render('intro.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.post()

    def post(self):
        self.render('intro.html')
```

It should work, if it doesn't add a comment :)

Also you can read some [tornado tutorial](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Thank you,
I think that would be my answer!

Comment: Can you just use `get = post` instead?

Comment: i'm not sure about "get = post" but i'm sure about my version